# Padding large numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Another numpy array handling question:
I have an approx. 2000³ entries numpy array with fixed size (that I know), containing integers. I want to pad the array with another integer, so that it's surrounded in all dimensions. This integer is fixed for the whole padding process.

```
example (2D)
1----->000
       010
       000
```

I have two ideas, leading to that result:

1. Creating a larger numpy array, containing the padded values and "slicing" the old area in the padded:

   ```
   padded=np.zeros((z+2,x+2,y+2))
   padded[1:z+1,1:x+1,1:y+1]=olddata
   ```
2. Using np.insert or hstack,vstack,dstack to add the values:

   ```
   padded=np.insert(data,0,0,axis=0)
   padded=np.insert(data,x+1,0,axis=0) etc.
   ```

The Problem is, that all these methods are not in-place and allocate a new array (1.) or copy the old one (2.). Is there a way to do the padding in-place? I know, that since numpy 1.7. there's the numpy.pad module. But that also seems to use some kind of allocation and overriding (like in my 1. way).

Comment: Could you work with a padded array to begin with?

Comment: @JanneKarila : I would not know how to start with a padded array? I have the rawdata and on some point I have to pad it or don't I?

Comment: How do you get the raw data into a NumPy array? Perhaps you could read it into a slice inside the padding at that point.

Comment: @JanneKarila I could do that, but I need to create the Padding as an array before, which takes a lot of time and memory (np.ones(2000,2000,2000) for example takes nearly 4 seconds)

Comment: Instead of np.ones you could use np.empty and slice assignments to set the padding.

Comment: @JanneKarila : I'm going to profile the running time of that as well. Maybe it's an advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add padding in-place because there is no room for it in the memory layout. You can go the other way though: allocate the padded array first, and use a view into it when accessing unpadded data.

```
padded = np.empty((2002,2002,2002))
padded[0] = 0
padded[-1] = 0
padded[:,0] = 0
padded[:,-1] = 0
padded[:,:,0] = 0
padded[:,:,-1] = 0

unpadded = padded[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1]
```